# How to prove the intersection of closed set is non empty?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> A decreasing sequence of nonempty closed sets in a metric space must have nonempty
> intersection.

I think it should be right, but have no idea how to prove that.

Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 4):

This is false. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric and the sequence of sets $I_n=[n,\infty)$. This is a decreasing sequence of closed sets, but the intersection is empty.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

For a metric space, this is true iff $X$ is compact. E.g. in $X=(0,1]$, usual metric, the sets $A_n = (0,\frac{1}{n}]$ are closed in $X$ but have empty intersection.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!